# Strict standards vs fatal error / concrete extension vs abstract implementation

Tags: php, oop

I noticed PHP behaves differently depending on whether a class is subclassing a concrete base class or implementing an abstract base class method or interface with respect to homogeny in method signatures. Consider these two examples

```
//----------------------------
// Strict Error
//----------------------------
class C { function blah(ArrayAccess $a) {} }

class D extends C { function blah($a) {} } // <- No type-hint in subclass method

//----------------------------
// Fatal Error
//----------------------------
interface A { function blah(ArrayAccess $a); }

class B implements A { function blah($a) {} } // <- No type-hint in subclass method
```

Here's the output

> Strict Standards: Declaration of D::blah() should be compatible with
>   C::blah(ArrayAccess $a) PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of B::blah()
>   must be compatible with A::blah(ArrayAccess $a)

**My question** - Why would PHP treat these two scenarios differently, historical reasons perhaps? Seems to me like the same problem either way.

I suppose you can *get away with it* in the concrete case since the subclass doesn't *have* to call the parent class' implementation in its implementation. Either way, I'm still curious.

Comment: Maybe interesting for you: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.extends -> `When overriding methods, the parameter signature` **should** `remain the same or PHP will` **generate an E_STRICT level error** `...` And interfaces: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php#language.oop5.interfaces.implements -> `The class implementing the interface` **must**  `use the exact same method signatures ... failure to do so will result in a fatal error ...` I think the thing is, that in the first case you **should** use the same signature and the other can't work

Comment: With an interface you are **"forcing"** the class which implements it to implement all methods. When you extend from another class you can overwrite it and you just **"should"** use the same signature when you do so, but you don't have to

Comment: Thanks for these links, but it doesn't speak to the *why*, which is really what I'm after. The explanations from the manual are no more informative than the error messages themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the formal words to explain the difference but here is how I see things.

An interface is a public contract for an implementation. As a contract, you must follow the rules defined in the interface. Not following them break the contract, so that's a fatal error.

A class extension may define its own rules. These rules should be similar to the base class otherwise things get a bit weird when you swap an implementation by an other. But if rules are differents but implementation is correctly handled, that's "just" a strict error.